# FATAL: no free slots for adding new region - AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android

Estoy en etapa de aprendizaje y estoy obteniendo el siguiente mensaje de error:

- *Emulator: crashhandler_die: fatal: hax_set_phys_mem_general: FATAL: no free slots for adding new region*
- *Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)*

¿Alguien tiene una sugerencia de como solucionarlo? Lo raro es que antes me andaba bien la aplicación, y ahora ya no.
Gracias.

Comment: Modificaste algo en el código y dejo de funcionar?

Comment: Hola! Te ha compilado o instalado siempre y luego dejo de instalar o nunca pudiste cargar el emulador?

Comment: Tenes memoria suficiente en el emulador? se suelen quedar sin espacio rapido, proba borrar aplicaciones instaladas en el emulador

Comment: Hola, si ya le agregue mas memoria a ambos almacenamientos pero sigue sin funcionar. Lo raro es que no tengo ninguna otra app instalada en el emulador salvo la que estoy tratando de ejecutar. Lo que es también un poco raro es que hace unos días el mismo código funcionaba lo mas bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probablemente el espacio asignado para almacenamiento interno y externo se termino, considera aumentar el espacio de almacenamiento definido para tu Android Virtual Device.

Abre el AVD Manager

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

modifica estas propiedades aumentando el espacio de almacenamiento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, ahi modifique los parámetros, lo reinicie y anduvo bien.